# Why are "double-barrelled surnames" called as such?

Tags: vocabulary, history

Why are double-barrelled surnames called "double-barrelled"? Wouldn't it make more sense if it was just referred to as "double surnames" or something like this? How did the expression "double-*barrelled*" comes from, and why was "barrel" added?

Comment: You can find the original meaning here: https://www.oed.com/oed2/00068968 - in the sense of a double-barrelled gun.  It has since developed a figurative meaning.

Comment: Note also that it's a colloquialism. The 'proper' term would be _compound surname_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin, and most literal application of 'double-barreled' lies with firearms (typically a shotgun) that have two barrels mounted side by side or one beneath the other, ie "*a double-barreled shotgun*'.

From this, there are numerous figurative uses, '*double-barreled names*' being just one. A '*double-barreled question*' is one that demands a single answer on two separate issues. And, to '*let someone have both barrels*' means to verbally attack or criticise someone forcibly.